# How to group events by multiple terms?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

How can I group by year and month? My query works if I leave 1 term, for example, `Month`. But I cannot group by multiple terms.

```
GET traffic-data/_search?
{
 "size":0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": {
          "VehiclePlateNumber": "111"
        }}
      ]
    } },
    "aggs" : {
        "years" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "Year"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "months" : { "by_month" : { "field" : "Month" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question's query is already close, try this:

```
GET traffic-data/_search?
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "VehiclePlateNumber": "111"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "years": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Year",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "months": {
          "terms": {
            "size": 12, 
            "field": "Month"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit - I am assuming your month is a string keyword field. Let me know if this is not the case (and please include the mappings) and I will revise.